# Is the set of all possible binary strings countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Determine whether the given sets are countable or uncountable. Justify your answers either with bijections or using results/methods.
>
> The set of all possible binary strings. Note a binary string is a sequence of 0s and 1s.

If a binary string consists only of 0s and 1s, then is it even possible to find a bijection for it?

Comment: Finite binary strings or infinite binary strings or both?

Comment: @kimchilover Doesn't matter, I've answered both ways.

Answer (score 6):

If the strings are of finite length, they are countable. A bijection from them to the set of positive natural numbers is given by $f(s)=1s_2$, where $1s$ denotes prepending 1 to $s$.

If the strings are of *infinite* length, they are uncountable. The bijection of prepending a radix point turns them into the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$, which were themselves shown uncountable by Cantor.

Comment: I'm not sure prepending a radix point to an infinite binary string gives you a bijection to $[0,1]$ but that doesn't matter, seeing as Cantor's theorem is simpler to prove for binary strings than for real numbers.